# Jquery find link in Div - open as defined in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, target

I need some div's to work as a clickable link. I already found the solution for jquery. Unfortunately this solution is always window.location or window.open. This is not suitable for us, since we have a lot of div's and the urls are already defined with _blank or same window.

I have to admit, that I am not sure, how I can look for the function that I need, since I have almost no knowledge of Javascript and the functions of it.

This is the code for the script, that I found:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$(".textlink").click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href");
        return false;
    });  
});
```

and this is one box with target=_blank

```
<div class="textlink texticon texticon-top"><a href="http://term1caq/WebCAQ.Net/App.QBD/DocumentView.aspx?id=429" target="_blank">Text in DIV</a></div>
```

The expected result would be, that the whole div is clickable but the target will be taken from the href of the div and not predefined in the script.

Comment: Instead of using a Javascript band-aid to fix this, change the CSS of the inner `a` element so that it fits the full width/height of the parent `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to trigger click on found anchor tag instead of setting its href to window.location

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(".textlink").click(function () {
        $(this).find("a:first").click();
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
$('.textlink a:first').click(function() {
  window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textlink texticon texticon-top"><a href="http://term1caq/WebCAQ.Net/App.QBD/DocumentView.aspx?id=429" target="_blank">Text in DIV</a></div>
```